# Looping through multiple images in xml file with php code

Tags: php, xml, image, loops

Below is my PHP code and XML file, I have been trying with so many different echos to loop through my images in my XML file to display each image to correct product but can only display the first image to all three products.

XML code:

```
<my_products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
         <image> csuT.jpg</image> 
        <name>Champion T-Shirt</name>
        <price>18.00</price>
        <description>
            Get the perfect look to let everyone know you are a stylish fan! 
        </description>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <image> webBook.jpg</image> 
        <name>C# Programming: Analysis to Program Design</name>
        <price>192.00</price>
        <description>
            Your hands-on guide to Microsoft Visual C# fundamentals with Visual Studio 2017
        </description>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>3</id>
        <image> calcPic.jpg</image> 
        <name>Calculator TI-BAII Plus 10DIG/24CASH</name>
        <price>39.00</price>
        <description>
            Performs common math as well as various financial functions 
        </description>
    </product>
</my_products>
```

PHP code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    $script_images="";
    $script_products="";
    $script_product_prices="";

    //Loop through the products defined in the products.xml file
    foreach ($xml->product as $r) 
    {
        $script_images.="products[".($r->id)."]=\"".($r->image)."\";\n";
        $script_products.="products[".($r->id)."]=\"".($r->name)."\";\n";
        $script_product_prices.="product_prices[".($r->id)."]=\"".($r->price)."\";\n";
    ?>  
        <div>
        <p class="lead">
            <h3 class="pull-right no-top-margin"><?php echo $currency_symbol;?><?php echo $r->price;?></h3>
            <h3><?php echo "<image src='csuT.jpg' 'calcPic.jpg' 'webBook.jpg'/>";?></h3>
        </p>
            <h3><?php echo $r->name;?></h3>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $r->description;?>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <?php
        //If there is details link set for the product, show a Details button
        if(trim($r->details_link)!="")
        {
        ?>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://<?php echo str_replace("http://","",trim($r->details_link));?>"</a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="javascript:AddToCart(<?php echo $r->id;?>)">Add to Cart</a>
     </div>
    <hr/>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <script>
    var currency_symbol="<?php echo $currency_symbol;?>";
    var products=Array();
    <?php echo $script_images;?>
    var product_images=Array();
    <?php echo $script_products;?>
    var product_prices=Array();
    <?php echo $script_product_prices;?>
    </script>
```

Comment: There is only 3 product containing one image each: so «can only display the first image to all three products» is expected with the code you provide.

Comment: How can I fix it, am just learning this for the first time. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to extract the image from the XML (the same way as done for the Javascript) and I've added a `trim()` to remove any spaces round the field...

```
    <h3><?php $image = trim($r->image);
    echo "<image src='$image'/>";?></h3>
```

Also add trim to...

```
$script_products.="products[".($r->id)."]=\"".($r->name)."\";\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this? :

```
<h3><?php echo "<image src='csuT.jpg' 'calcPic.jpg' 'webBook.jpg'/>";?></h3>
```

your src attribute is static and you must change it

Comment: That's exactly the line I have been changing with many codes I found online but nothing worked.